# Can you render swigjs inside scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I'm using nodejs + express + swigjs for a website of mine and got stuck. I have a `<select>` that contains `<option>`s populated by a variable passed to my template. Upon selection of an option I want to, inside of a `<script>`, find that selection and use it elsewhere on the page.

Can you do this with swig? I looked all over their documentation and haven't found a filter/option/tag that lets this happen. I would love to see an example. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's what I'm trying to do.

My controller renders the template with the following instruction:

```
res.render('pages/edit.html', {
    page: res.locals.page,
    content: results,
    media: media,
    directives: directives
});
```

In my template I want to do the following:

```
$('#addpiece').click(function(event){
    var jsoned = {{ media }};
    console.log(jsoned);
});
```

`media` is an array of objects.

But no matter how I filter the data it won't pass without a javascript error occurring.

Comment: added the relevant portions :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [json filter](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#json) and you should be set!

```
$('#addpiece').click(function(event){
    var jsoned = {{ media|json }};
    console.log(jsoned);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{ media }}` needs to produce javascript-proper code. It can't be just an object. Try converting it server-side to JSON and then read it by your client-side javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved adding "safe" instead of "json".

```
    $('#addpiece').click(function(event){
    var jsoned = {{ media|safe }};
});
```

where the array is like:

```
media = [ [ 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' ],  [ 'a3', 'b2', 'c2' ] ]
```